# Can't start Tor after upgrade to newest version

Tags: mac, update

I Have just upgraded Tor after having been prompted to do so when starting the version, which worked. Now, at the re-start of Tor I get the attached pop-up screen.[image: screenshot of pop-up screen]
When restarting I always come back to the same screen. When trying to "Copy Tor Log to Clipboard" it does something, but there is no log at all at the end. I can now even not see which version I am trying to start. I am working with OS 10.9.5.
Any advice what to do would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a lot of issues after upgrading to the latest Tor version. I dumped it and reinstalled tor 7.5.6 from the Tor archives.